# Refresh token for Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, google-api, google-oauth

I have an application that uses Google APIs in some places, and I want to avoid having the user login every time. Currently, I only receive a Google access token in the response, not a refresh token. How can I obtain the refresh token?

This is the function I use to when the user click to login with google:

```
    authenticate() {
      const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
        scope: [
          "All_NECESSARY_SCOPES",
        ].join(" "),
        callback: (res) => {
          this.accessToken = res.access_token
          this.loadClient()
        }
      })
      client.requestAccessToken()
    },
```

It works for getting the access token. And I need the refresh token, Please Help Me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side JavaScript does not return a refresh token.  It would be a security risk.

If you want a refresh token you need to use a server sided language like Node.js